# Double vs doubleValue in Java

Tags: java

if a method returns a Double, why would we call the method "doubleValue" on it?  it already returns a double and in calculations, appears to evaluate correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prior to Java 1.5 auto-boxing (and unboxing) didn't exist in Java. So, you would need this to extract the underlying primitive from a Double.

If you are unfamiliar with auto-boxing, you can read more here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: So from the link it suggests that you take a performance hit from autoboxing and autounboxing.  In a performance critical loop, could you then call myDouble.doubleValue() to avoid having to unboxing penalty?

Comment: @MedicineMan No, the unboxing is just that the compiler will turn `double foo = myDouble` into `double foo = myDouble.doubleValue()` for you -- calling the method explicitly doesn't matter. The bulk of the performance hit is in having created the boxed `Double` object in the first place (and, probably to a lesser degree, in having to access heap memory instead of a stack var to get at the value).

Comment: yshavit nailed it. The only way to avoid the penalty is to avoid any transition between Double <--> double. However, that's often impractical, especially if you want to use any Collections. Also, it would be a *very* rare case where this is truly a performance bottleneck for an application.

Answer (score 1):

You call 'doubleValue' on a Double object to convert from the boxed Object to the primitive data type.  Since most of the time the Double is auto-unboxed to a double, you usually don't need to do this, but if you want to be explicit in your conversion, you can call this method.

Answer (score 1):

You'd call `doubleValue` if you need to obtain a `double` from a `Double`. The former is a primitive type, while the latter is a wrapper object type, which basically encapsulates a primitive value inside an immutable object. If possible (and I'm saying this without knowing exactly the purpose of your code), use `double` for all your calculations; only use `Double` if you need to store the values in a `Collection` or `Map`; that's because object types consume more memory and may be subject to casting operations.

It's easy to mistake `double` with `Double` (same thing applies for the other primitive types vs. wrapper types), since the compiler will automatically convert from one to the other as needed in a process known as auto-boxing (and auto-unboxing), so a little care must be taken to use the correct type.

Comment: And just to add to this a bit, and explicitly state it: mathematical operations and tests (arithmetic, comparison, etc) can't be done with `Double`s, only `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

doubleValue returns a primitive *double* from the *Double* Object. Depending on the scenario, you would want to get the double out of a Double.